# MySQL - how to eliminate results with NULL value? (with code)

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL code

```
SELECT p.plant_name, 
       sum(data.value_1) totalvalue_1
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT date_format(date, '%Y-%m') ym 
          FROM data 
         WHERE data.id_fk = 1 
           AND date BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-04-01') dates
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT data.id_fk, 
                   data.plant_id_fk 
              FROM data 
             WHERE data.id_fk = 1) up
      JOIN plants p ON p.plant_id = up.plant_id_fk
 LEFT JOIN data ON date_format(data.date, '%Y-%m') = dates.ym
               AND up.id_fk = data.id_fk
               AND up.plant_id_fk = data.plant_id_fk
               AND category_1 = 'expenses'
  GROUP BY up.plant_id_fk
  ORDER BY up.id_fk, up.plant_id_fk
```

which outputs this result

```
aasd    74
qweqwe  20
tyutyu  NULL
bnmbnm  NULL
234234  NULL
```

I would like to completely eliminate the results containing NULL and get only this as my result:

```
aasd      74
qweqwe  20
```

I've tried using `is not null` in several clauses but none gave the result I need.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding a `HAVING` clause between your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`:

```
 group by up.plant_id_fk
 HAVING SUM(data.value_1) > 0
```